# Page not found in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I cannot access other modules(pages). I can access only public directory http://localhost:88/hotelrwanda/public. I put the project into development mode and enable error display but nothing. Can you give any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you setup the zend default rewrite rules?

**public/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: yes, I did but it is not working. I am using zend server. I don't think so that because of server

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /hotelrwanda/public/test123 was not found on this server.

Comment: then you didn't setup the .htaccess properly! maybe your server has no RewriteEngine installed, or it disallows setting it via .htaccess

Comment: but how come I have an access to the public folder?

Comment: this is my htaccess configuration

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

Comment: The public folder is physically, you can always call it. Try my example .htaccess

Comment: try to place the .htacces in your DocumentRoot and add `RewriteBase /hotelrwanda/public` before the `RewriteCond`s

Comment: Thank for you help, but it seems that it doesn't work. I tried to use your example. but nothing so far

Comment: Thank you, The problem was that `AllowOverride` was set `none`